# How to rerender template on collection update

Tags: meteor

Given this template

```
<template name="content">
  {{#each children}}
    I'm a child
  {{/each}}
  <button name="create">Create</button>
</template>
```

and this code

```
Template.content.children = ->
  Children.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('parent').children}})

Template.content.events
  'click button' : (event) ->
    child = Children.insert({created_at: new Date()})
    Parents.update(Session.get('parent')._id, {$push: {children: child}})
```

how can I get the template to be automatically updated? If found that if I change the 'parent' session variable to something else, then back to the original one, it works, I do see all the children, but I would like it to be automatic.

Basically, I just want a list of children to be automatically updated whenever I insert a new child. But obviously, I'm doing something wrong here... Maybe it's not the right approach at all?

Comment: How are you initially setting your `parent` session variable?

Comment: A simple Session.set('parent', parent). It looks like the parent is correctly updated (at least, the children list in the parent is, but the template doesn't refresh itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Template.content.children = ->
  parent = Session.get('parent')
  Children.find({_id: {$in: parent.children}})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
dep = new Deps.Dependency()

Template.content.children = ->
  dep.depend()
  Children.find({_id: {$in: Session.get('parent').children}})

Template.content.events
  'click button' : (event) ->
    child = Children.insert({created_at: new Date()})
    Parents.update(Session.get('parent')._id, {$push: {children: child}})
    dep.changed()
```

I don't really know why you initial code is not updating automatically since changes in collections induce reactivity in dependent functions, so this method just forces the reactivity.

**Edit**

I see the question is very old an Meteor changes a lot because it below 1.0, so its probably dew to the state of an old version. My response works for version 0.8.0.